# cant delete all records in IN clause mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running this query,

```
DELETE FROM media WHERE id IN ('19,18')
```

Its only deleting record with id 19 as you can see in the picture.

The column type of id is integer though.

[image]

Comment: `IN ('19', '18')` and not `IN ('19,18')`

Comment: Remove the inverted commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string which is being converted to the first integer (19). Remove the quotes.

`DELETE FROM media WHERE id IN (19,18)`

Comment: yeah @Strawberry suggested thanks